# Design of class relationships

Tags: c++, qt, class, relationship

I have a project in which user can build different objects. This application have few subwindows and some of them can modify one global object. There are three ways to modify such object:

1. Load from database object. (window1)
2. Modify it with a help of window with forms (buttons, lineedit...) (window2)
3. Modify it with a help of graphical window in which this object is shown (for example with a mouse).(window3)

The logic is next: if I have load from database new object then it should update object in window2 and window3. If I have changed object through the window2 then object in window3 should be updated, and window1 should be notified that object was changed. If I have changed object through the window3 then object in window2 should be updated, and window1 should be notified that object was changed.

Now the logic is next: object is stored in class with global access (singleton). Window notification is done through the signal-slot mechanism in qt.

Is there any other way to design it?

Answer (score 1):

It's good enough. But singleton is not so good pattern. The other way is to make one of the windows the creator and owner of the shared object, and put a pointer to the object to the other windows. After that you can initialize signal-slot connections as usual.